# Is Firebase E-mail Auth example secure?

Tags: javascript, security, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying the JS SDK of Firebase, naturally, I picked up the provided example and started to dive in.

[The example code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/email.html) is for e-mail sign in, hosting on Firebase.

What surprise me is that all password-compliance is made client-side:

```
...
    function toggleSignIn() {
      if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        // [START signout]
        firebase.auth().signOut();
        // [END signout]
      } else {
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        if (email.length < 4) {
          alert('Please enter an email address.');
          return;
        }
        if (password.length < 4) {
          alert('Please enter a password.');
          return;
        }
...
```

What mecanism prevent someone from opening the code in the console, removing the check, and registering under a empty string as e-mail/password?

Searching for firebase security only tell me that everything is made in HTTPS, and that server-side rules are customizable to prevent anyone not signed in from editing the DB, but what about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample code you link to is from the documentation of the [Firebase email+password authentication provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth). I recommend reading the documentation page too, instead of *just* the sample code in isolation.

When I try to create a user with a short password (`123`), the Firebase Authentication server responds with:

> {code: "auth/weak-password", message: "The password must be 6 characters long or more."}

As you can see, the server validates the strength of the password too.

It is quite common to perform validations both client and server side.

- Validations *must* be performed on the server to ensure that they can't be hacked around, as you said.
- By also validating the values client-side, you can ensure a better user experience. In this example: you can prevent the need for a round-trip to the server in case the user enters an invalid email address.

Comment: Your link point to the Android version of the doc, I think you meant to direct me to the [Web version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth). I will remeber your advice thought.

Comment: Yup, I tested with JavaScript but copied the wrong link. Fixed now.

Comment: Is the only requirement on Firebase the fact that it should be 6 chars long? Does this mean that a password like aaaaaa is sufficient to be accepted?