# Firebase 'createCustomToken' not recognized in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing "login with custom token". I found this snippet of code in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

```
firebaseAuth.createCustomToken(uid)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(String customToken) {
                                    // Send token back to client
                                }
                            });
```

I have put this code inside the 'onCreate' method and 'createCustomToken' is not being recognized:
[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: your link of the Firebase Documentation leads to the Admin SDK and not to the Android SDK. Are you sure that your link is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to all this... Does it mean I cannot create a custom token within my app? I used the signInWithEmailAndPassword method but then I read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991935/is-firebase-e-mail-auth-example-secure and was trying to find a better solution... Then I found about this signWithCustomToken method and I was trying to implement it via the link I posted...

Comment: no, you cannot create a token in your app. You can only create custom tokens on server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you try to mix up the Firebase Admin SDK with the Android SDK. The method createCustomToken is only available at the Admin SDK and not for the Android SDK. The docs for Android can be found here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/

The Admin SDK can only be used at server side