# Can not resolve FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid)

Tags: android, firebase

I want to add custom fields on firebase database after I am successfully authenticated without using createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) method.
This is my code:

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    current_uid = current_user.getUid();
    custom_token = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(current_uid);
```

This gives an error that can not resolve createCustomToken(uid).
Can anyone help me?

Build.gradle(Project)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shaileshkumar.firebase_glb"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: show `build.gradle` please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139689/firebase-createcustomtoken-not-recognized-in-android

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Added!  You can check

Answer (score 0):

In android SDK you have this method to get a token:

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```